# Text gets gray in release mode in flutter application

Tags: flutter

For some reason button text gets gray in release mode while being fine in debug mode. Here is the example of how it looks in debug mode:

[image: button with text]

And this is an example of how it looks like in release mode:
[image: button without text]

Code for the button is following:

```
                          
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil().setWidth(40)),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(263),
              height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(69),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil().setWidth(20)),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.success,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))),
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // some actions
                },
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Выбрать", style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryLight, fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(16)), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(ScreenUtil().setWidth(20), 0, 0, 0),
                            child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/forward.svg", height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(20), width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(20))
                          ),
                        ]
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          ]
        )
      ]
    )
  )
)
```

As you can see, I am using ScreenUtil for managing flexible layouts. Suspicion is that it somehow fails to do its job properly.

Can somebody explain what is going on here, why is the perfectly renderable app behaves this way in release mode when no overflows are reported? And, what is more important, how to fix it (preferably without changing font size as it is already small enough)?

Comment: Try removing the ```color``` arg in the FlatButton and see if this happens again or not. I think it might be some issue with the Theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted the code, now it looks like this:

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil().setWidth(40)),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // some actions
        },
        child: Container(
          width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(263),
          height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(69),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil().setWidth(20)),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.success,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))),
          child:
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Выбрать", style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryLight, fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(16)), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(ScreenUtil().setWidth(20), 0, 0, 0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 20)
                ),
              ]
            )
          )
        )
      ]
    )
  )
)
```

The process of adjustment was rather tedious as long as I had to build release versions to try every change of code on the phone where issue is reproducible (everything is fine on emulator, no gray rectangles reproduce there). First I found minimal code that worked without displaying unwanted gray rectangle and started building up step-by-step from there. Result is working button without unwanted side-effects. To be honest, now when I am able to compare buggy and working solutions, I still don't know what exactly was wrong with previous code sample. Position of FlatButton wrapper didn't matter much, grey rectangle was just bigger if it was moved up the document tree. I guess getting rid of extra Row declaration eventually made it work.